# Dynamic Pathfinding A* Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm trying to use A* pathfinding in Unity3D, and it works if the target remains stationary. However, if the target moves, the units will still follow the same path. Find the code for each unit below (attached to the seeker objects):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    float speed = 20;
    Vector3[] path;
    int targetIndex;

void Start() {
    PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position,target.position, OnPathFound);
}

public void OnPathFound(Vector3[] newPath, bool pathSuccessful) {
    if (pathSuccessful) {
        path = newPath;
        StopCoroutine("FollowPath");
        StartCoroutine("FollowPath");
    }
}

IEnumerator FollowPath() {
    Vector3 currentWaypoint = path[0];

    while (true) {
        if (transform.position == currentWaypoint) {
            targetIndex ++;
            if (targetIndex >= path.Length) {
                yield break;
            }
            currentWaypoint = path[targetIndex];
        }


        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,currentWaypoint,speed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;

    }
}

public void OnDrawGizmos() {
    if (path != null) {
        for (int i = targetIndex; i < path.Length; i ++) {
            Gizmos.color = Color.black;
            Gizmos.DrawCube(path[i], Vector3.one);

            if (i == targetIndex) {
                Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, path[i]);
            }
            else {
                Gizmos.DrawLine(path[i-1],path[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

now if I try to use it for dynamic pathfinding (target moving around, and paths updating) by changing void Start() to void Update(), this will not work. The response will cause weird unit behaviour, moving forth and back all the time or not completing the path etc.
Now I don't know the exact cause for this, might be because of coroutines?
Anyway, how could I alter the code so that correct dynamic pathfinding will be the result?

Thanks in advance!

*P.S. all remaining source code is to be found here:* http://bit.ly/pathfindingSource

Comment: In your FollowPath it looks like theres never a way for the path to change unless you break bc youve gone to far. Youd need another piece of logic to say "if target moved, get a new path"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "fixed" the problem, with a for now good enough solution.

First of all, I make the pathfinding dynamic by requesting a new path in every waypoint. Second of all, the pathfinding keeps on going even after reaching the target, by some logic which checks every frame whether the units are far enough again to repeat the coroutine. If so, the old coroutine is stopped and a new coroutine is started.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
float speed = 20;
Vector3[] path;
int targetIndex;

bool  newRequestReady;

void Start() {
    PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position,target.position, OnPathFound);

    newRequestReady = false;
}

void Update(){
    float distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, target.position);
    Debug.Log(distance);

    if(distance < 5){
        StopCoroutine("FollowPath");
        newRequestReady = true;
    }
    else if(distance >=10 && newRequestReady){
        PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position,target.position, OnPathFound);
        StopCoroutine("FollowPath");
        newRequestReady = false;

    }
}

public void OnPathFound(Vector3[] newPath, bool pathSuccessful) {
    if (pathSuccessful) {
        path = newPath;
        StopCoroutine("FollowPath");
        StartCoroutine("FollowPath");
    }
}

IEnumerator FollowPath() {
    Vector3 currentWaypoint = path[0];

    while (true) {

        if (transform.position == currentWaypoint) {
            PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position,target.position,OnPathFound);
            targetIndex=0;

            targetIndex ++;
            //Debug.Log(currentWaypoint);

            if (targetIndex >= path.Length) {
                targetIndex =0;
                path = new Vector3[0];
            //yield break;
            }
            currentWaypoint = path[targetIndex];
        }
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,currentWaypoint,speed * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null;
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the design of this logic isnt to optimal, try just recalculating the path when the next waypoint is reached:

```
IEnumerator FollowPath() {
    Vector3 currentWaypoint = path[0];

    while (true) {
        if (transform.position == currentWaypoint) {

           PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position,target.position, OnPathFound);

targetIndex = 0;
            targetIndex ++;
            if (targetIndex >= path.Length) {
                yield break;
            }
            currentWaypoint = path[targetIndex];
        }


        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,currentWaypoint,speed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;

    }
```

If you want to have dynamic pathfinding you need to recalculate the path evry time the next waypoint is reached, or have other logic, like having an event that fires when some objects moved - in handler you recalculate the path.

Comment: I've tried your method and it works until the units reach the target. It they reach the target and consequenty the target moves, they will stop following. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Also, it seems the variable targetIndex becomes redundant this way, as it always equals 1, right?

Comment: Yes it is redundant. I will try to edit the answer to your update.

Comment: Even if I remove the if (targetIndex >= path.Length) {
                yield break;
            } alltogether, the units still stop following after they reached the target. I can't seem to find the problem

Comment: The only possibility I see is that 'currentWaypoint == null' so path is filled with nulls after last waypoint. Please let me know if that is true.

Comment: I get IndexOutOfRangeException. Refers to Vector3[] currentWaypoint = [0], and to currentWaypoint = path[targetIndex]

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but are you still gonna edit the answer like you said?

Comment: Hey, sorry I cannot find the problem right now and I am very busy. But what I would suggest is to restart coroutine when the target is reached and moved.